# CSS Selector Not Working... and it really should

Tags: html, css

Thanks in advance for any help, I've been banging my head on the desk for a couple hours trying to figure this out, but I admit I'm bamboozled.

I have a navigation div:

```
        <div class="projectNav clearfix">
            <div class="previous <?php if(!get_previous_post()){ echo 'inactive'; }?>">
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', '&larr; %title'); ?>
            </div>              
            <div class="next <?php if(!get_next_post()){ echo 'inactive'; }?>">                     
                <?php next_post_link('%link', '%title &rarr;'); ?>              
            </div>                  
        </div> <!-- end navigation -->
```

And these styles, sitting under a media query in the stylesheet.

```
.projectNav {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;    
    padding-top: 10px;  
    float: none;
}

.projectNav div{
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
{

.projectNav .next {
    float: right !important;
{

.projectNav .previous {
    float: left !important;
{
```

The first two styles are affecting the HTML nodes, but the last two never show up at all. I have to be able to select the 'previous' and 'next' elements to float them to either side of the page, but for the life of me I can't get the styles to work on them. I've tried changing the class name, giving them IDs, everything I could think of. Nothing. Does it have to do with the php in the class field?

Help!

Comment: You should provide resulting HTML code, not source PHP code. BTW, it's typical for PHP to strip some whitespace around its tags.

Comment: Is that a mistake in your copy/paste or do you actually have your curly-braces facing the wrong way in your real code?

Comment: You've got to be freaking kidding me. It's always the easy stuff. Thanks guys!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Please don't remove the cause of the error from the question. A little formatting is fine, but now, there's no question left to answer.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol :) I was staring at the question for like 5 min trying to figure out what brackets you were talking about.

Comment: @user1815312: No kidding at all. You should provide resulting HTML code, not source PHP code. Given that PHP usually strips whitespace around its tags, you most likely end up with `previousinactive` class name without space between `previous` and `inactive`.

Comment: @MaratTanalin PHP never strips whitespace before the opening tag. Only after the closing tag, a newline character will be stripped.

Comment: @Yoshi: Even if so (I always use a template engine that has exactly one `echo`—after all code is already generated and accumulated in a variable), HTML-related question should contain client-side HTML code, not server-side PHP code.

Comment: @GolezTrol My bad. I thought it was a typo of no significance, as often is the case in newcommers' posts. My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

The closing curly braces on the 2nd, 3rd nd 4th style are wrong:

```
.projectNav {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;    
    padding-top: 10px;  
    float: none;
}

.projectNav div{
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
} /* not { */

.projectNav .next {
    float: right !important;
} /* not { */

.projectNav .previous {
    float: left !important;
} /* not { */
```

Comment: Ugh, that was nasty! Awesome discovery!

Comment: The closing brackets doesn't look that way in the question?